# Update Submodule on GitHub without Git

Tags: github, git-submodules

Say there are 2 repositories on GitHub: repository A and repository B.

The commit history of A is `3f72ab` -> `a562fe`.

Now B has a *submodule* `A @ 3f72ab`, which is an older version of A.

How to update B's *submodule* to its latest version on GitHub?  (in this case, `A @ 3f72ab` -> `A @ a562fe`) 
I don't want to use Git to pull a remote repository B and then update its submodule and push it.  I want to use **only GitHub** to do that.  IOW, update a submodule online.